# Rails: Copy data for specific tables between databases / environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-migrations

In a project I'm working on, I have certain tables that are used as lookup tables. They have a pretty complex structure and could be a bit long, so I went with database tables instead of YAML. Is there a way I can transfer those tables **along with the data** between different environments?

I have my development and test environment in heroku. So any heroku based ways to transfer data will be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1):

You may benefit from [database seeding](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html)

--

A relatively simple procedure - you can pre-populate your datatables using the `db/seeds.rb` file:

```
#db/seeds.rb
Model.create({option: "value"})
```

You can then use `rake db:seed` to populate the datatables

--

Probably not what you're looking for exactly, but certainly an option

Comment: Definitely an option. I have to say, I was spoiled by some Microsoft GUI tools before, that'll automate some of the database transfer scripts for me. I'll resort to this as a last option.

Comment: Just to confirm - does the export code in the page you specified exclude data already seeded / in seeds.rb? Is that what this line does? 

delete_if {|key, value| ['created_at','updated_at','id'].include?(key)}.to_s.gsub(/[{}]/,'')})

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure what that is! I think it's basically that if you're trying to import `new` data from existing, it will remove all the attributes which may prevent the database from being populated. The main reason for this is ActiveRecord will automatically populate the `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes for you